# WPF Expander overlay used in ItemsControl

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've been searching for some time but all solution I find only tackle parts of my issue.
I'd like to have an ItemsControl with each item containing an Expander. On expanding, the Expander's content should be shown as an overlay overlapping the other items in the ItemsControl and not moving them down.

The following XAML-Code does exactly as supposed to with one big issue: The Expander's content does not overlap the other items but is hidden behind them. I suppose this is due to the ZIndex as the following items in the ItemsControl are added after the Expander's content.

I managed to set one single Expander's ZIndex to 99 using style triggers but this seems to be a too complicated and error-prone solution. Any thoughts?

```
<Window x:Class="WpfTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Height="350"
        Width="525">

  <Window.Resources>

    <x:Array x:Key="items"
             Type="sys:String" 
             xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
      <sys:String>One</sys:String>
      <sys:String>Two</sys:String>
      <sys:String>Three</sys:String>
      <sys:String>Four</sys:String>
    </x:Array>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="template">
      <Grid Background="Red" Margin="0,0,0,10">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
          <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
        <Canvas Height="25" Grid.Row="1">
          <Expander ExpandDirection="Down" Header="Header" Grid.Row="1">
            <Expander.Content>
              <TextBlock Height="80" Text="Content" Background="Yellow" />
            </Expander.Content>
          </Expander>
        </Canvas>
      </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>

  </Window.Resources>

  <Grid>
    <ScrollViewer>
      <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{StaticResource items}"
                    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource template}"
                    HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
      </ItemsControl>
    </ScrollViewer>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: have you actually tried using ZIndex? Setting ZIndex (for both Canvas and Grid) right in the DataTemplate seems not work. If it worked, using it was not that bad.

Comment: I tried putting Panel.ZIndex at various positions and combinations, nothing worked. Only by having a style trigger setting the ZIndex to 99 on MouseOver worked from all the things I tried so far.

Comment: I've also just found out that the problem is caused by the `ZIndex` of the Items, normally all the Items have the same ZIndex, but the after items always have higher precedence in this case. So using Trigger is OK. That trigger should listen to the `IsExpanded`, you change the `ZIndex` of only the related item, and it should work.

Comment: Have you considered placing your overlay content in an adorner layer instead?

Comment: @KingKing: Using a popup seems much cleaner and bulletproof.

Comment: @MikeStrobel: Yes, using adorners will work but I thought this issue might be quite easy to solve and an adorner seemed to be little overkill.

Comment: Right at first I knew that using something like a Popup was the solution. (because in case you want to render something out of its parent control, using Popup is a good choice although Canvas is also usable). However I found out that changing the Z-Index appropriately could solve this issue. It's some kind of ***interesting problem***. So it's worth trying to solve it that way. The next problem (sprung from your problem) is try changing the control's properties from inside its `DataTemplate`, currently there is no elegant way to do this (maybe we need some custom attached property).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's going to be tricky to achieve this in the way you are attempting it.  The problem is the nested structure -- since each `Canvas` is nested inside a `Grid`, you won't be able to control its z-index relative to other Canvas element.  To illustrate this, here is a schematic of the visual tree created by your current markup:

```
<StackPanel>              <!-- items panel -->
    <ContentPresenter>    <!-- item wrapper -->
        <Grid>
            <Canvas>
            </Canvas>
        </Grid>
    </ContentPresenter>
    <ContentPresenter>    <!-- item wrapper -->
        <Grid>
            <Canvas>
            </Canvas>
        </Grid>
    </ContentPresenter>
</StackPanel>
```

With reference to the above, your goal will be to have the `Canvas` elements appear in front of the siblings of its parent `ContentPresenter`.  This is impossible in this hierarchy, because `ZIndex` only applies relative to siblings of the same parent element.  Now, there might be ways you could massage the above into a flat structure so that you could then apply ZIndex your expanded content as needed.

However, I think an easier and more natural approach would be to use [`Popup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.popup(v=vs.110).aspx) elements for the expanded content.  A Popup is a framework primitive that is located outside of the visual tree, and will always sit on top of your other content.  You can use a ToggleButton or something similar to create the "expand" effect.  For example:

```
<StackPanel Grid.Row="1">
    <ToggleButton x:Name="PopupToggle" Content="Expand" />
    <Popup IsOpen="{Binding IsChecked,ElementName=PopupToggle}">
        <TextBlock Height="80" Text="Content" Background="Yellow" />
    </Popup>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Thank you explaining the reason behind. Using the popup is as easy to integrate and works fine except that the popup has to be moved manually when the toggle item/window changes location.

Comment: @LaD1Da the reason behind is not related to `Canvas` zindex (I mean this answer explains that part wrong). It's related to the ***zindex of the item*** (such as `ListBoxItem`, `ListViewItem`, ...). Normally the z-indices are equal but the after items always have higher precedence (like as their zindex is higher than the before ones'). I in fact created a view-model with appropriate Z-Indexs sorted in descending order, and set the zindex for the items via binding. It works expectedly.

Comment: @KingKing: Yes, that's correct. Still, the popup is the easiest solution because is does not require any additional code/properties/bindings.
Just for curiosity I implemented a custom behavior setting the ZIndex of the items in the ItemsControl with decreasing values. Works perfectly. I'm not sure how to solve this with bindings as you did.